# Почему код запускается без вывозова?

Tags: javascript, form, валидация

подскажите пожалуйста почему при обновление страницы происходит проверка что форма заполнена? Вроде повесил запуск на событие submit

```
(function () {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.js-form')
    const emailMask = /^[A-Z0-9._-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z0-9.-]+$/i;


    if( forms.length <1){
        return
    }

    forms.forEach(function (form){
        console.log('новая форма')
        var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input')
        var submitButton = form.querySelector('.js-submit-button')

        if(!submitButton) {
            return
        }

        submitButton.addEventListener('click', validateForm(inputs))

        form.addEventListener('submit', function (e){
            e.preventDefault()
            validateForm(inputs)
        })
    })

    function validateForm(inputs){
        inputs.forEach(function (input){
            validateInput(input)
        })
    }

    function validateInput(input){
        console.log(input.type)

        if(input.type === 'email') {
            if(input.value.length < 1 || !emailMask.test(input.value)) {
                addError(input)
            }else if(input.value.length < 1) {
                addError(input)
            } else {
                removeError(input)
            }
        }

        if(input.type === 'text') {
            if(input.required) {
                if(input.value.length < 1) {
                    addError(input)
                } else {
                    removeError(input)
                }
            } else {
                removeError(input)
            }
        }

        if(input.type === 'checkbox'){
            if(input.required) {
                if(!input.checked){
                    addError(input)
                }else{
                    removeError(input)
                }
            }else {
                removeError(input)
            }
        }
    }

    function addError(input){
        console.log('error')
        if(input.type === 'checkbox'){
            let parent = input.closest('div')
            parent.querySelector('label').classList.add('label-error')
        }else {
            input.classList.add('input-error')
        }
    }

    function removeError(input){
        console.log('good')
        if(input.type === 'checkbox'){
            let parent = input.closest('div')
            parent.querySelector('label').classList.remove('label-error')
        }else {
            input.classList.remove('input-error')
        }
    }

    function showSuccess(form) {
        form.classList.add('form--success');
        const submitBtn = form.querySelector('.js-form-submit');

        setTimeout(() => {
            submitBtn.classList.add('disabled');
            form.classList.add('form--success');
            form.reset();
        }, 2000)
    }
})();
```

Comment: submitButton.addEventListener('click', validateForm(inputs)) в данной строке вызывается функция validateForm(inputs), а нужно ее просто передать, но учитывая что в нее нужно передать параметры, можно воспользовать анонимной функцией, которая будет служить оберткой submitButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>validateForm(inputs))

Comment: @Roman спасибо, все верно написали:)